# how to create java zip archives with a max file size limit

Tags: java, zip

I need to write an algorithm in java (for an android app) to read a folder containing more folders and each of those containing images and audio files so the structure is this: `mainDir/categorySubfolder/myFile1.jpg`

My problem is that I need to limit the size of the archive to 16mb and at runtime, create as many archives as needed to contain all my files from my main `mainDir` folder.

I tried several examples from the net and I read the java documentation but I can't manage to understand and put it all together the way I need it. Has someone done this before or has a link or an example for me?

I resolved the reading of the files with a recursive method but I can't write the logic for the zip creation.

I'm open for suggestions or better a working example.

Comment: What are some of the examples you tried from the net? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084823/filenotfoundexception-no-such-file-or-directory this was my initial post which had a mistake I now fixed but now 2 more arose.... the first one is that I can't seem to set the size of the ZipEntry and the second one is that when I try to extract the files I get the error 'compression method not supported'

Comment: also because I can't set the size of the ZipEntry my logic doesn't work so it always creates only one archive

Comment: How big is the complete zip file? Can it be stored on the disk or even held in memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a huge zip file into multiple volumes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243992/how-to-split-a-huge-zip-file-into-multiple-volumes)

Comment: my files we're 8,5mb and the zip was actually larger at 9mb. yes I have read/write permission and free access to memory card to store anything on it

Comment: Do the individual parts have to be proper zip files or will you combine them later to one zip file again?

Comment: they will have to be separate individual zips... I will not recombine them later no

Comment: Does it work when writing to disk and not a memory card?

Comment: No. Its the same. I can only successfully create a single archive from several files using some simple example code from oracle website or other tutorial sites, but I can't implement my logic for the max zip size...

Comment: [Below code is my solution to split zip file in directory structure to chunks based on desired size. I found the previous answers useful so, wanted to contribute with similar but little more neat approach. This code is working for me for my specific needs, and I believe there is room for improvement.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214186/4396142)

Comment: @androidu, I have same requirement to zip the files from source directory and zip has 5 MB size restriction and have to zip remaining files with another zip.Could you share your code to fix my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) is a great library that can create multi-part zip files.

```
net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("out.zip");
ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
zipFile.createZipFileFromFolder("path/to/source/dir", parameters, true, maximum size);
```

You can find more examples on their web-site.

Comment: -minimum of splitted file is 60MB
-only can create splitted zip from files on HDD

Answer (score 2):

I am using below code/class to split and zip a large amount/size of files.
I have tested this class on below

- number of uncompressed files : 116
- total size (uncompressed) : 29.1 GB
- **ZIP file size limit (each) : 3 GB** [MAX_ZIP_SIZE]
- total size (compressed)   : 7.85 GB
- number of ZIP file (splited as **MAX_ZIP_SIZE**): 3

you have to change the value of **MAX_ZIP_SIZE** to 16(MB)*1024*1024=16777216-22(zip header size)=**16777194**.
In my code, MAX_ZIP_SIZE set to 3 GB ([ZIP has limitation of 4GB on various things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#ZIP64)).

> final long MAX_ZIP_SIZE = 3221225472L; //3 GB

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class QdeZip {

    public static String createZIP(String directoryPath, String zipFileName, String filesToZip) {
        try {
            final int BUFFER = 104857600; // 100MB
            final long MAX_ZIP_SIZE = 3221225472L; //3 GB
            long currentSize = 0;
            int zipSplitCount = 0;
            String files[] = filesToZip.split(",");
            if (!directoryPath.endsWith("/")) {
                directoryPath = directoryPath + "/";
            }
            byte fileRAW[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directoryPath + zipFileName.toUpperCase()));
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            FileInputStream entryFile;
            for (String aFile : files) {
                zipEntry = new ZipEntry(aFile);
                if (currentSize >= MAX_ZIP_SIZE) {
                    zipSplitCount++;
                    //zipOut.closeEntry();
                    zipOut.close();
                    zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(directoryPath + zipFileName.toLowerCase().replace(".zip", "_" + zipSplitCount + ".zip").toUpperCase()));
                    currentSize = 0;
                }
                zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                entryFile = new FileInputStream(directoryPath + aFile);

                int count;
                while ((count = entryFile.read(fileRAW, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    zipOut.write(fileRAW, 0, count);

                    //System.out.println("number of Bytes read = " + count);
                }
                entryFile.close();
                zipOut.closeEntry();
                currentSize += zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
            }

            zipOut.close();
            //System.out.println(directory + " -" + zipFileName + " -Number of Files = " + files.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return "FileNotFoundException = " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "IOException = " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception = " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return "1";
    }
}
```

> I have returned all *Exception Messages* as String to work with it. this
> my own case related to project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see [How to split a huge zip file into multiple volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243992/how-to-split-a-huge-zip-file-into-multiple-volumes) just suggests keeping track of the archive size so far, and when it approaches some arbitrary value (which should be lower than your max), it'll decide to start a new file. So for a 16MB limit, you could set the value to 10MB and start a new zip whenever this is reached, but if you reach 9MB and your next file zips down to 8MB, you'll end up with a zip bigger than your limit.

The code given in that post didn't seem to work for me because 1) it got the size before the ZipEntry was created, so it was always 0 and 2) it didn't write out any zip :-) If I've got that wrong - let me know.

The following works for me. For simplicity, I've taken it out of the Wrapper and just have it all in main(String args[]). There are many, many ways this code could be improved :-)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ChunkedZipTwo {

    static final long MAX_LIMIT = 10 * 1000 * 1024; //10MB limit - hopefully this 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] files = {"file1", "file2", "file3"};
        int i = 0;
        boolean needNewFile = false;
        long overallSize = 0;
        ZipOutputStream out = getOutputStream(i);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        for (String thisFileName : files) {
            if (overallSize > MAX_LIMIT) {
                out.close();
                i++;
                out = getOutputStream(i);
                overallSize = 0;
            }

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(thisFileName);
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(thisFileName);
            out.putNextEntry(ze);
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
            overallSize += ze.getCompressedSize();
        }
        out.close();
    }

    public static ZipOutputStream getOutputStream(int i) throws IOException {
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("bigfile" + i + ".zip"));
        out.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a try :) and yes you are right. I got the same behaviour from my sample code. I will be back with my results :D Thank you

Comment: Thanks, I managed with some minor modifications to your code to achieve my desired result! :D

Comment: No problem, what did you have to change?

Comment: I added a BufferedOutputStream between the ZipOutputStream and the FileOutputStream like this:  FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipDirectory + "/zip.part" + i + ".zip");
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

Comment: Can you tell me what will the unzip function look like for the above zip?