# Apache Common Compress - Split Zip file

Tags: java, apache, compression, apache-commons-compress

I have successfully zip or unzip file by using Apache Common Compress library. Now the problem is, the compressed file needs to be send via FTP/email and 10 MB is the maximum limit of the file to be sent.

1. So I need know the way to generate file(s) with custom size?
2. How can I uncompress the file(s)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must you use Apache Common Compress? Otherwise this answer might be interesting for you: [how to create java zip archives with a max file size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104889/how-to-create-java-zip-archives-with-a-max-file-size-limit)

Comment: Yes, Commons Compress doesn't support multi-volume ZIP archive, yet, so not using it is likely the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to their official user guide for zip under "Multi Volume Archives"
:

> If you want to create a split ZIP archive you use the constructor of `ZipArchiveOutputStream` that accepts a `File` argument and a size. The size determines the maximum size of a split segment - the size must be between 64kB and 4GB. While creating the archive, this will create several files fillowing the naming convention described above. The name of the `File` argument used inside of the constructor must use the extension `zip`.

source: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html