# How can I programmatically identify a zip or rar file is splitted or not in java?

Tags: java, zip, rar

I need to identify the whether a particular zip or rar file is splitted or not.

Is there any library to deal with archive file in java?

Comment: ZIP is in the standard API package java.util.zip. Maybe it throws an exception, when an archive is splitted or corrupt. For rar files i don'T know.

Comment: Do you know whether you're specifically talking about split or spanning zips/rars? Or do you need to support both?

Comment: i need for both zip and rar,its ok even if it is two different solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243992/how-to-split-a-huge-zip-file-into-multiple-volumes this should help you

Answer (score 1):

Usually multivolume RAR Files will follow the following name convention:

```
somefile.part01.rar
somefile.part02.rar
somefile.part03.rar
```

Or, using the older naming convention, like this:

```
somefile.r00
somefile.r01
somefile.r02
```

For Zip files:  A split archive with 20 split files the files are typically named (replace ARCHIVE with the name of your archive) :

```
ARCHIVE.z01 
ARCHIVE.z02 
... 
ARCHIVE.z19 
ARCHIVE.zip
```

Note that the last file is the .zip file.

For more information take a look at:

http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zip.html

http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/154/