# How can I break up a large zip file into smaller zip files?

Tags: java, zip

I'd like to break up a single zip file that holds multiple files and create a zip file for each of the ZipEntries. That is: 
MainZipFile.zip ---> Zip1.zip, Zip2.zip, Zip3.zip 
Where the (right-hand-side) RHS zip files correspond to ZipEntrys inside MainZipFile.zip.

I'm using Java, and I'd like to do it without decompressing and re-compressing, which is the obvious solution. I'm not even sure if this is even practically possible.

I was thinking of creating empty RHS zip files, then using ZipInputStream to read the contents of an ZipEntry in MainZipFile.zip and deposit the contents into the corresponding RHS zip file, but I can't figure it out.

Edit 1:

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE_IN_BYTES=2*1024; //2KB
void tryReading(){
  String filepath = getTempFilepath();
  ZipFile mainZipFile = new ZipFile(filepath);
  InputStream inForEntry = getInputStreamForEntryWithName(checkpoint.getFilePath(), mainZipFile);
  ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(inForEntry);
  byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE_IN_BYTES];
  int countOfBytesRead = zin.read(data); //returns -1
  zin.getNextEntry();
  countOfBytesRead = zin.read(data);//returns -1
}

private InputStream getInputStreamForEntryWithName(String name, ZipFile mainZipFile) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry entry = mainZipFile.getEntry(name);
    return mainZipFile.getInputStream(entry);
}
```

Comment: Using ZipInputStream seems like the right approach.  Which part of it is giving you trouble?

Comment: @VGR , when I try to read from the ZipInputStream `zin`, I get -1 immediately. When I read from the InputStream `inForEntry` that I used it works, but this stream is uncompressed.

Comment: This seems to be a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243992/how-to-split-a-huge-zip-file-into-multiple-volumes

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc on the ZipInputStream read()

Reads from the current ZIP entry into an array of bytes. If len is not zero, the method blocks until some input is available; **otherwise, no bytes are read and 0 is returned.**

**Returns:
the actual number of bytes read, or -1 if the end of the entry is reached**

I believe you're reading through the whole file and reaching the end. Wrap your read in a loop and read through a byte at a time and see if you can get it to output anything.

Comment: Even if I put it in a loop, I'd still have to read the first 2KB of the file. I'm not sure why it's returning -1. The zip file is ~44MB. I read the first 2KB just to make sure that it's reading anything at all, and it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

The `InputStream` you get from the `ZipEntry` gives you the result of decompressing the zip entry. Wrapping a `ZipInputStream` around it doesn't make any sense. The input the `InputStream` provides to the `ZipInputStream` isn't zipped data, it is plaintext. It can't possibly work.

In any case the data provided by `ZipInputStream` is more plaintext, not zipped data, so it can't possibly meet your objective.

You will have to read the `InputStream` and create a new zip file from it in the normal way you create zip files.

Comment: I don't want to decompress it though. I want to take out the ZipEntry uncompressed and then store it as a zip file. If I simply write the InputStream from ZipEntry, I'd be extracting (decompressing) the ZipEntry.  I'm hoping I can take it out without decompressing, but I don't know if that'll be possible.

Comment: You can't do that at all, let alone the way you're trying to do it, which doesn't make sense. You're wrapping a `ZipInputStream` around a stream that delivers plaintext, and even if that works, which it doesn't, the `ZipInputStream` would deliver you plaintext, not zipped data. You have to read the `InputStream` and create a new zip file from it in the normal way you create zip files.

Comment: I'll accept the answer that it can't be done easily. And I'm seeing now that my way won't work, but how do you know that it can't be done at all? I'm asking because I don't see why it would not be possible. I don't know a lot about zip file structures.

Comment: It can't be done at all with Java API. Maybe you could write something from scratch that looks inside the ZIP file, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative seems to use a **zip file system** to "file copy" a selection of files from one to another zip.

This zip file system is already provided in Java SE for the `jar:` protocol. So if you have an URI `file:/xxx/yyy.zip` make an URI `jar:file:/xxx/yyy.zip`.

```
URI sourceZipURI = URI.create("jar:" + sourceZip); // "jar:file:/.../... .zip"
URI targetZipURI = URI.create("jar:" + targetZip); // 

Map<String, Object> senv = new HashMap<>(); 
FileSystem sourceZipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(sourceZipURI, senv, null);

Map<String, Object> tenv = new HashMap<>(); 
tenv.put("create", "true");
FileSystem targetZipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(targetZipURI, tenv, null);

// Example of a file copy:
Path sourcePath = sourceZipFS.getPath("/file1.txt");
Path targetPath = targetZipFS.getPath("/file1.txt"); // Or"/"
Files.copy(sourcePath, targetPath);

// Example of a zip traversal:
Files.walkFileTree(sourceZipFS.getPath("/"),
    new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                    BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                      throws IOException {
             ...
             return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });

sourceZipFS.close();
targetZipFS.close();
```

A ZipInputStream/ZipOutputStream is possible too. For that search for some example code; as correct code would take some changes/additions.

Comment: Oh, this looks promising! Do you know if I can buffer the copy process? I'd like to be able to stop and resume.

Comment: @joshuar Note that this still decompresses and recompresses. There's no apparent way around that.

Comment: The method visitFile could just compose a `List<Path>` and then you could do your own stop/resume file by file. Or make your own copy, by using your own BufferedInputStream, see Files.

Comment: @EJP, do you have a source that it does decompress and recompress? I don't think it's obvious from the code.