# How to split file to multiple files while compressing file using java zip compression?

Tags: java, io, zip, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

Suppose, there is a requirement while compressing file using java zip compression that output file size shouldn't be more than specific limit and if it is more than specific limit, it should generate multiple files of size equal or less than size limit.

```
For e.g.,
Input requirements:

input folder/ file.txt (949MB)
Max limit of compressed file: 100MB

Output:
Output folder / file0.txt.zip (100MB)
Output folder / file1.txt.zip (100MB)
.....
.....
Output folder / file9.txt.zip (49MB)
```

Please share your thoughts on this as I didn't find method which can help me in getting compress file size at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a huge zip file into multiple volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243992/how-to-split-a-huge-zip-file-into-multiple-volumes)

Comment: @Turamarth It talks about multiple files and not about single huge file into multiple zips.